# ListView Items aren't displaying on Main Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I'm a beginner in android development. I'm trying to send data from an ArrayList of Type Workout Item to the MainActivity using an Adapter, but I don't understand base adapters very well. Here is my code:

WorkoutActivity.java:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.SystemClock;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Chronometer;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class WorkoutActivity extends Activity {

    WorkoutItemAdapter workoutItemAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout);
    }




    public class WorkoutItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        int rowCount = 1;
        List<WorkoutItem> workoutsList = getDataForListView();

        public WorkoutItem getWorkout(int position)
        {
            return workoutsList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) WorkoutActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.workout_item, parent, false);
            }

            TextView workoutNum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.workout_col);
            TextView workoutTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_col);      

            WorkoutItem workout = workoutsList.get(position);

            workoutNum.setText(workout.workoutNum);
            workoutTime.setText(workout.time);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return workoutsList.size();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public WorkoutItem getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return workoutsList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }
        public void addRow() {
            rowCount++;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.workout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    public List<WorkoutItem> getDataForListView()
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String workoutTime = prefs.getString("Workout Time", "");

        List<WorkoutItem> workoutsList = new ArrayList<WorkoutItem>();

        for(int i = 0; i < (workoutsList.size() + 1); i++)
        {
            WorkoutItem workout = new WorkoutItem();
            workout.workoutNum = "Workout " + (i+1);
            workout.time = workoutTime;

            workoutsList.add(workout);
        }

        return workoutsList;
    }

    public void startAndStopTimer(View view)
    {
        long totalTime = 0;

        Button startAndStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Chronometer c = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
        if(startAndStop.getText().equals("Start"))
        {
            c.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + totalTime);
            c.start();
            startAndStop.setText("Pause");

        }
        else
        {
            totalTime = c.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            c.stop();
            startAndStop.setText("Start");
        }
    }

    public void save(View view)
    {
        // create broadcast receiver saying ...saved.

        // Add ArrayList value to arrayList
        Chronometer timer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);

        SharedPreferences timerSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = timerSettings.edit();
        editor.putString("Workout Time", timer.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();

        // go back to main activity.
        Intent intent = new Intent(WorkoutActivity.this, OverviewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void cancel(View view)
    {
        // go back to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(WorkoutActivity.this, OverviewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    }
```

OverviewActivity.java:

```
    import edu.uark.csce.razorrunner.WorkoutActivity.WorkoutItemAdapter;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class OverviewActivity extends Activity{ 

    WorkoutItemAdapter workoutAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);
        LoadPreferences();  
        LoadListView();
    }
    private void LoadListView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ListView workoutList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.workout_list);
        workoutList.setAdapter(workoutAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.overview, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void LoadPreferences()
    {       
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            String Name = sharedPreferences.getString("Name", "");

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView.setText(Name);
    }

    public void openWorkoutActivity(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(OverviewActivity.this, WorkoutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    public void openProfileActivity(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(OverviewActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    public void openHistoryActivity(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(OverviewActivity.this, HistoryActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    }
```

activity_overview.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="edu.uark.csce.razorrunner.OverviewActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/profileButton"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:onClick="openProfileActivity"
            android:text="Profile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/workout_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="195dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.19" >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startNewWorkout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:onClick="openWorkoutActivity"
        android:text="Start New Workout!"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_workout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="edu.uark.csce.razorrunner.WorkoutActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:onClick="cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"
        android:text="Save"
        android:onClick="save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:text="Start"
        android:onClick="startAndStopTimer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_col"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="New Workout"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time_col"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Calories Burned"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Duration"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="0" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">

        <requestFocus />
    </TextView>

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView1"
        android:text="Chronometer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'd like to show the workout number and duration for each list item every time I click Save, but currently all I get is a blank ListView every time I click Save. Any help and/or additional sources on this topic would be useful.

Comment: seems your listview adapter with problem, you need constructor, then instantiate it before set it to listview, after load data to list then call 'workoutAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' display list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope two mistakes you made.

```
 public List<WorkoutItem> getDataForListView()
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String workoutTime = prefs.getString("Workout Time", "");

    List<WorkoutItem> workoutsList = new ArrayList<WorkoutItem>();

    for(int i = 0; i < (workoutsList.size() + 1); i++)
    {
        WorkoutItem workout = new WorkoutItem();
        workout.workoutNum = "Workout " + (i+1);
        workout.time = workoutTime;

        workoutsList.add(workout);
    }

    return workoutsList;
}
```

I guess you are trying to add data to list view. Since you are creating new List using

```
 List<WorkoutItem> workoutsList = new ArrayList<WorkoutItem>();
```

workoutsList.size() will return zero. your loop iterates till list size+1. (only one time )

then you need to pass the List from WorkoutActivity to OverviewActivity.

change WorkoutActivity insert following code

```
public class WorkoutActivity extends Activity {

WorkoutItemAdapter workoutItemAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.workout, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}

public List<WorkoutItem> getDataForListView() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String workoutTime = prefs.getString("Workout Time", "");

    List<WorkoutItem> workoutsList = new ArrayList<WorkoutItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < (10+ 1); i++) {
        WorkoutItem workout = new WorkoutItem();
        workout.workoutNum = "Workout " + (i + 1);
        workout.time = workoutTime;

        workoutsList.add(workout);
    }

    return workoutsList;
}

public void startAndStopTimer(View view) {
    long totalTime = 0;

    Button startAndStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Chronometer c = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    if (startAndStop.getText().equals("Start")) {
        c.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + totalTime);
        c.start();
        startAndStop.setText("Pause");

    } else {
        totalTime = c.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        c.stop();
        startAndStop.setText("Start");
    }
}

public void save(View view) {
    // create broadcast receiver saying ...saved.

    // Add ArrayList value to arrayList
    Chronometer timer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);

    SharedPreferences timerSettings = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = timerSettings.edit();
    editor.putString("Workout Time", timer.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();

    // go back to main activity.
    Intent intent = new Intent(WorkoutActivity.this, OverviewActivity.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("stock_list", getDataForListView());
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

public void cancel(View view) {
    // go back to main activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(WorkoutActivity.this, OverviewActivity.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("stock_list", getDataForListView());
    startActivity(intent);

    finish();
}

}
```

and OverviewActivity to this

```
public class OverviewActivity extends Activity{ 


List<WorkoutItem> workList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);
    Intent i = getIntent();  
    workList = i.getStringArrayListExtra("stock_list");
    LoadPreferences();  
    LoadListView();
}
private void LoadListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ListView workoutList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.workout_list);

    WorkoutItemAdapter workoutAdapter= new WorkoutItemAdapter(workList);
    workoutList.setAdapter(workoutAdapter);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.overview, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void LoadPreferences()
{       
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String Name = sharedPreferences.getString("Name", "");

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView.setText(Name);
}

public void openWorkoutActivity(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(OverviewActivity.this, WorkoutActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
public void openProfileActivity(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(OverviewActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
public void openHistoryActivity(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(OverviewActivity.this, HistoryActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

public class WorkoutItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    int rowCount = 1;
    List<WorkoutItem> workoutsList ;

  public  WorkoutItemAdapter( List<WorkoutItem> list) {
  workoutsList=list;
}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) WorkoutActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.workout_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView workoutNum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.workout_col);
        TextView workoutTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_col);      

        WorkoutItem workout = workoutsList.get(position);

        workoutNum.setText(workout.workoutNum);
        workoutTime.setText(workout.time);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return workoutsList.size();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public WorkoutItem getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return workoutsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    public void addRow() {
        rowCount++;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

try these code. I have not yet tried, hope will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume OverviewActivity.java is your main Activity which in return opens WorkoutActivity ?

Comment: OverviewActivity is the main Activity. Correct.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't initialise workoutAdapter...only declared....
hence workoutAdapter is null....which means the size of adapter is 0 ...which means no rows for list view...

before setting the adapter to listview ..you must have to initialize workoutAdapter
i.e.

```
workoutAdapter=new WorkoutItemAdapter(getDataForListView());
```

create the adaper contructor and pass the list array

```
public class WorkoutItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    int rowCount = 1; //don't know about that
    List<WorkoutItem> workoutsList;

    public WorkoutItemAdapter(List<WorkoutItem> tmp)
    {
        this.workoutsList=tmp; //setting the list array to datamember of this adapter
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In WorkOutItemAdapter  List<WorkoutItem> workoutsList = getDataForListView();
// check the size of the list is zero or null
In WorkOutItemActivity you do like this

 WorkoutItemAdapter workoutItemAdapter = new WorkoutItemAdapter();
 ListView workoutList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.workout_list);
 workoutList.setAdapter(workoutAdapter);*
```